# Match and Group by Date

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mysql query, need to convert into mongodb for latest version Driver\Manager mongodb.so using php executeCommand or executeQuery.

```
SELECT created_time, count(id) AS total
FROM `tweets`
WHERE created_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND active = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(created_time)
```

Tried so far is:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].":27017");
    $cond = [ 'created_time' => ['$gte' => '(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY'], 'active' => 1 ];
    $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'aggregate' => 'collection_name',
        'pipeline' => [
            ['$match' => $cond],
            ['$group' => ['_id' => '$created_time', 'total' => ['$sum' => '$_id']]],
        ],
        'cursor' => new stdClass,
    ]);
    $cursor = $manager->executeCommand('db_name', $command);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        $result[] = $document;
    }
```

Comment: it would be nice if you can add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok, I have updated with my so far tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.

Update your `$cond` with below. Rest looks fine.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));
$cond = [ 'created_time' => ['$gte' => $date], 'active' => 1 ];
```

Update grouping key `_id` to include date part only.

```
['$dateToString' => ['format' => "%Y-%m-%d", 'date' => '$created_time']]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need replacement of following mysql query. In group by $created_time is db field that contains datetime but I need group by date only without time.

SELECT created_time, count(id) AS total FROM tweets WHERE created_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND active = 1 GROUP BY DATE(created_time)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I did this:

['$group' => ['_id' => ['$dateToString' => ['format' => "%Y-%m-%d", 'date' => '$created_time']], 'total' => ['$sum' => '$_id']]],

but got error:
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'can't
 convert from BSON type string to Date'

Comment: Looks like you have created time stored as string in db. Can you try changing it to bson date type ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to mongodb, I have created the records in the following way, I don't know how can I change this into bson data type as I have't defined data type of any field.

$data = array("text" => SpecialCharacterCoversion($text),
                    "owner_id" => $user_id,
                    "created_time" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
$bulk->insert($data);

Comment: Try `"created_time" => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(new DateTime() -> getTimestamp()*1000)` when creating new entries.

Comment: Appreciated Veeram, Thank you.